# Why the DataNode configuration disappears and reported "cannot pull system configurations" warning in Apache IoTDB Version 1.3?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to start a stand-alone Version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB. The cluster management has been started, and the jps can check the DataNode and ConfigNode, but the DataNode disappears after 1 minute. There is no error information in the `confignode_all.log`, and there is a warning reported in IoTDB server: `WARN o.a.i.db.service.DataNode:263 - Cannot pull system configurations from ConfigNode-leader, because: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException`.Why did this problem happen and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the fact that Apache IoTDB confignode is slow to start in your environment, and the Datanode needs to rely on Confignode to start successfully.
You can try starting Confignode first, waiting for it to start successfully, and then starting the DataNode.